# Adding rows to JTable using a loop

Tags: java, swing, loops, user-interface, jtable

I am trying to add rows to my table using a loop. The code I have is as follows:

```
 import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JTable;
 import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Test {

    public void testCase(){
       DefaultTableModel listTableModel;
       listTableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
       for(int i = 1; i < 25 ; i++){
           String rowString = "Quiz #" + i;
           listTableModel.addRow(new Object[]{rowString, "ICON", "ICON"});
       }

       JTable listTable;
       listTable = new JTable(listTableModel);
       listTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
       listTable.setCellEditor(null);
       listTable.setBounds(37, 143, 397, 183);
       //listTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(300);
       JFrame frame = new JFrame();
       frame.add(listTable);
       frame.setVisible(true);
       frame.pack();
   }

/**
 * @param args
 */
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       Test tester = new Test();
       tester.testCase();

   }

   }
```

Using a hard coded table, this method returns a functional table. hard coded looks like:

```
 listTableModel = new DefaultTableModel( new Object[][] {{1,1,1}{2,2,2},{3,3,3}}, new String[] {"Col1, Col2, Col3});
 return listTableModel;
```

This code gives me no result. I am inserting it into a panel and it is not showing up in the panel

I'm not sure why this is not working because all research I have done has pointed me to doing it like this... 
any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: For better help sooner, consider making a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org)

Comment: What is not working?! Whats the expected and actual outcome?

Comment: @R.J it is not creating the table. When I try to edit (like set a column size) it gives me an index out of bounds exception. If I comment out my code that edits my table and just add it to my frame it does not even produce a table.

Comment: Your question is not demonstrating the problem that you are having.. consider making a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) and providing valid code.

Comment: @nachokk It is hard for me to make a SSCCE because this code is a small part of a three class GUI ... this is the only part that is giving me problems

Comment: An SSCCE might contain 3 classes, but only one class in the source file can be declared `public`.

Comment: I have added a working example of the code I am using. It shows that the code does not create a table. If the commented line is uncommented, the out of bounds exception will occur

Comment: @dic19 I had that in there as a test to see if it was my loop or the actual model. I took that line out now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you should use Call by value and initialize Row and Column Objects for the table, Try this code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Test {

private static final Object[][] rowData = {};
private static final Object[] columnNames = {"Column 1", "Column 2","Column 3"};

public void testCase() {
    DefaultTableModel listTableModel;
    listTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(rowData, columnNames);
    for (int i = 1; i < 25; i++) {
        String rowString = "Quiz #" + i;
        listTableModel.addRow(new Object[]{rowString, "ICON", "ICON"});
    }

    //listTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(50, 50);

    JTable listTable;
    listTable = new JTable(listTableModel);
    listTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    listTable.setCellEditor(null);
    listTable.setBounds(37, 143, 397, 183);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(listTable);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Test tester = new Test();
    tester.testCase();

}
}
```

Comment: I was missing the initial row{} and column fields. Thank you so much!