# Adding Rows/Cels to a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, indexoutofboundsexception, tablemodel

so basically I have a JTable and a DefaultTableModel d to which I've added 5 columns using the d.addColumn() method. The thing is, I don't quite understand how I need to add rows to a JTable, I've tried everything from using setValueAt as well as this:

```
d.addRow(new Object[] { <myArrayListWithCells>.get(i) });
```

^ what this does is basically adding all the cells in my array underneath the first column. So how do I make it so that it actually puts the cells in their correct place under the correct column? I tried using a nested for loop inside for the columns but it didn't work. 
I get a long list with exception errors out of this which looks like this:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:470)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.setValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:665)
at ListItemListener.mouseClicked(ListItemListener.java:69)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6508)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4501)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Could somebody please help? Thanks.

Comment: so basically ..., this question isn't answerable without your SSCCE or MCVE

Comment: short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value for <myArrayListWithCells>

Comment: Take a look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19188307/adding-rows-to-jtable-using-a-loop/

Comment: Not sure if this is the right answer, but did you try `d.addRow(myArrayListWithCells.toArray());` ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a proper question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java add/remove row to JTable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18615089/java-add-remove-row-to-jtable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, on form load your model contains **0** rows therefore you are getting such kind of exception you need to set the `rowCount` of your model as:

```
d.setRowCount(nrOfRows); //nrOfRows specified earlier in class code
```

---

**Useful Link**

[DefaultTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html)